# Apache Spark -- How to return java bean using spark UDFs

Tags: java, apache-spark

Hello and Thank you in advice.

My program is written in java.
I want to return java bean with spark UDFs but I failed.

TrySpark.java

```
StructType nameSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
new StructField("familyName", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
new StructField("firstName", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
});
Encoder<NameBean> nameEncoder = Encoders.bean(NameBean.class);
Dataset<NameBean> csvds = spark.read().format("csv")
                          .schema(nameSchema).load(filePath).as(nameEncoder);
csvds.show();
            
UDF1<String, IdsBean> setIdUdf = new UDF1<String, IdsBean>() {
   public IdsBean call (String familyName) {
    IdsBean ids = new IdsBean(); 
    ids.setId1(String.valueOf(familyName.length()));
    ids.setId2("2");
        return ids;
   }
};
            spark.udf().register("setIdUdf",setIdUdf,Encoders.bean(IdsBean.class).schema());
Dataset<Row> dataset = csvds.withColumn("newCol",functions.callUDF("setIdUdf",functions.col("familyName")));
dataset.show();
```

IdsBean.java

```
public class IdsBean {
    private String id1;
    private String id2;
    public String getId1() {
    return id1;
    }
    public void setId1(String id1) {
    this.id1 = id1;
    }
    public String getId2() {
    return id2;
    }
    public void setId2(String id2) {
    this.id2 = id2;
    }
}
```

Exception

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (~.IdsBean@4cce0e94) of the type (~.IdsBean) cannot be converted to struct<id1:string,id2:string>`

Can I return java bean? And if it is possible, how should I do it?

Comment: What would you want to return a bean in the UDF, why not return a struct?

Comment: I want to return multiple columns.
How can I return a struct in the UDF ?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to build a UDF that returns an object with several fields, you don't need a java bean. You can use tuples or even rows.

```java
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
    DataTypes.createStructField("id1", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("id2", DataTypes.StringType, true)
});

// A UDF that returns a tuple
UDF1<String, Tuple2<String, String>> setIdUdf = new UDF1<String, Tuple2<String, String>>() {
    public Tuple2<String, String> call (String familyName) {
        return new Tuple2<>(String.valueOf(familyName.length()), "2");
    }
};
spark.udf().register("setIdUdf", setIdUdf, schema);

Dataset<Row> dataset = csvds
    .withColumn("newCol", functions.callUDF("setIdUdf", functions.col("familyName")));
dataset.show();
```

Note that you can also use a Row object if you like like this:

```java
UDF1<String, Row> setIdUdf2 = new UDF1<String, Row>() {
    public Row call (String familyName) {
        return Row.fromTuple(new Tuple2<>(String.valueOf(familyName.length()), "2"));
    }
};
```

And there is also a more concise way using lambda functions:

```java
// Same UDF as before but it returns a Row
UDF1<String, Tuple2<String, String>> setIdUdf3 = (
    (String familyName) -> new Tuple2<>(String.valueOf(familyName.length()), "2")
);
```